# Catastrophic initialization failure! Shutting down null WAB due to: null // NPE @ WabBundleProcessor.initContext(WabBundleProcessor.java:460)

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7, equinox, spring-portlet-mvc

when I deploy a maven module spring mvc portlet Liferay7.3 ga1 in the Lr7 portal, I got this error can anyone support please !
Is there something missing?

This is the stack trace:

```
2020-02-28 14:41:14.570 ERROR [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-ce-portal-7.3.0-ga1/osgi/war][WabBundleProcessor:244] Catastrophic initialization failure! Shutting down null WAB due to: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.initContext(WabBundleProcessor.java:463)
        at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.init(WabBundleProcessor.java:140)
        at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer._initWabBundle(WebBundleDeployer.java:159)
        at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer.doStart(WebBundleDeployer.java:88)
        at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory$WABExtension.start(WabFactory.java:113)


2020-02-28 14:41:14.572 ERROR [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 4c0cd32f-6426-4a62-bb58-24614ae72cc6][Framework:93] FrameworkEvent ERROR
org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: Exception in com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.ServletContextHelperRegistrationServiceFactory.getService()
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse.factoryGetService(ServiceFactoryUse.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse.getService(ServiceFactoryUse.java:111)



...

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Any support is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: You mention 7.2, the directory is named 7.3 - which is it? Also: can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Liferay 7.1.

As for my case, it was a maven dependency that was missing when the war was built.
So i'm guessing there is something you are doing wrong before deploy.

Maybe this link will help you : [Liferay forum](https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/79147107)

Regards.